# automatically reference user to node by date field

Tags: 7, datetime, entities

I'm totally stuck in this situation, can't find any solution, please help!

i have content profile date field "date of birth" (y-m-d) and node "horoscope" with multiple value date field (m-d). When new user registers his date of birth I need to auto-reference to the horoscope node with same date. Year is not important in that case.

For example:

I have "horoscope" nodes: (title - dates)

Horoscope A - 01.23, 03.11, 05.02
Horoscope B - 02.14, 07.01
Horoscope C - 11.11
Horoscope D - 02.10, 03.02, 05.07, 09.14
After new user registers his account with date of birth: 1977.07.01, I need "horoscope_reference" field to automatically assign him "Horoscope B" or if entered date of birth: 1234.03.02, "horoscope_reference" should be assigned to "Horoscope D" and so on...

any suggestions please? (drupal 7)

Thank You..

Comment: That sounds like you need to create a module which adds a field entry on node save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [computed field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module for this. This lets you add your own conversion logic into the field (using PHP) that will be processed on entry. So download and enable the module, then add a field for your horoscope, then in the settings field, you want to add your PHP logic, ex (roughly):

```
$date = new DateTime($entity->field_profile_dob[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
$month = $date->format('m');
$day = $date->format('d');
if (($month = 1) && ($day < 21)) {
    $answer = "some sign";
} else if .. etc.
```

That will take some time to write that logic. You might be better off putting this in a module then leaving it in the settings. There are dozens of examples in the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/126522) that should help you get started on this.

Comment: thanx a lot, I did it already by creating my own module. I have horoscope signs as nodes so logic is much simpler, i just had to find signs by its date field... But your suggestion is appreciated... Thank You.